# SSL and remove extension .html via HTACCESS without redirect chains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I see that all these scripts for removing .html extension seem not to work via SSL. I solved the issue with  new script but now i am creating a 2 step redirect chain which i do not like for SEO reasons - and with your help :) i hope to get it back to a redirect step / hop.

My script is

```
RewriteBase /


RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.carpro.ro/$1 [R=301,L]

# Force WWW prefix
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.([a-z]{2,4})$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


# Remove .html extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.html
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

but it seems to create a cascade of redirects.

Is there any better version which

1. 301 http to https for all pages of the site
2. redirect non WWW to WWW
3. remove .html extension and do not leave a trailing /

The script above works but with redirect cascades which i do not like

http://www.domain.com/something.html
does a 301 Redirect
https://www.domain.com/something.html
then again a 301 Redirect
https://www.domain.com/something

rather than
http://www.domain.com/something.html
a single redirect to
https://www.domain.com/something

Any ideas on optimising this?

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.carpro.ro%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=302,L]

# Force WWW prefix
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=302,L]

# Remove .html extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.html
RewriteRule (.+?)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: This helped thank you @anubhava. You can remove SERVER_PORT 80 part because it is better be done http to https redirection with "Redirect permanent" in apache sites-available...

Answer (score 0):

You can try below Rewrite Rules to eliminate html extension

RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

And the following rewrite rule for trailing / removal

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

Hope this helps

Comment: In this case the 2 steps still remain. non http, redirects to https which redirects to path without html extension. What i am searching for would be rather  ***http:// www.domain.com/something.html a single redirect to ***https:/ /www.domain.com/something